# Can we make a circle with irrational radius?

Tags: circles, irrational-numbers

Is it possible for us to theoretically make a circle with irrational radius?

Comment: Why should it not be possible? What's so special about irrational numbers that makes you think it's more difficult to draw such a circle? Also, what tools do we have available? The classic straightedge and compass?

Comment: `irrational radius` ...in *what* units?

Comment: So, he is probably looking for constructible numbers

Comment: Given a unit measure when can construct a circle of any constructable radius (of which many are irrational) and we can not construct any that are not.

Comment: Circumscribe a square, for example. The diameter of the circle is $\sqrt2$ times the square’s side length.

Comment: What do you mean by “construct”?

Answer (score 4):

From Pythagoras Theorem, we can construct length of $\sqrt{2}$.

We can then construct the circle.